# Using VBA to vlookup each comma separated value in one cell and return emails

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping someone knows how to vlookup multiple comma separated values in one cell and provide semicolon separated output in the adjacent cell. 
I have noticed two other instances of this question on Stack Overflow but, unfortunately, both referred to using formulas (textjoin and vlookup) to solve this issue. Due to another VBA formula I am using, I need the final output to result solely in the text information, not in a formula. Is there any way to do this using VBA? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Start with the `Split` function. You'll want `Join` too.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, I you gave me a good idea on how to approach this. Ended up figuring out a workable solution.

Comment: Where did `Timothy` come from in your desired results? I've posted an answer but neglected the fact he came out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to use the vlookup with the split using Ben's suggestion. Only issue is it puts a semicolon at the start of my email string, which is no issue for me but may be for another user.

```html
Sub FINDEM()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, I As Long
    Dim WrdArray() As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'last row with data in Column A
        For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Cells      'loop through each cell in Column A
            strg = ""
            Sal = ""
            WrdArray() = Split(cel, ", ")
            
            For I = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
                Sal = Sal & "; " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WrdArray(I), Sheet1.Range("d2:e9"), 2, False)
            cel.Offset(0, 1) = Sal
            Next I
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Join` would eliminate the problem of a leading `;`. Also `cel.Offset(0, 1) = Sal` should probably be after `Next I` - you only want to write to the cell after you've finished looping through `WrdArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so without iteration, plus you might want to take into consideration removing duplicates. For example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long
Dim arr As Variant, arrA As Variant, arrB As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Get last used row and data into memory
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A2:B" & lr).Value

    'Join and transpose column A:A and B:B into their own array
    With Application
        arrA = Split(.Trim(Join(.Transpose(.Index(arr, 0, 1)), ",")), ",")
        arrB = Split(.Trim(Replace(Join(.Transpose(.Index(arr, 0, 2)), ";"), Chr(10), "")), ";")
    End With

    'Write array to sheet
    .Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrA) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrA)
    .Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrB) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrB)

    'Remove duplicates from column D:E
    .Range("D2:E" & UBound(arrA) + 1).RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2), xlNo

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @JvdV. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work. It ends up dupliucating cells in column D, deleting those in column E, and nothing is provided in column B.

Comment: Can you share your sample data, maybe as a workbook, and I'll get this working. Worked perfectly for me when I recereated your data